# Error by publishing ASP.NET MVC site in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

An Error  **"Servername "TestingAzure73737DB" cannot be empty or null."** appears by creating new ASP.NET MVC web site with SQL Server (named "TestingAzure73737DB") in Azure. I have just started to using Azure. First 3 websites were created without any errors. But 2 sites, that I have created later gives me errors. I don't understand sence of this error. This is name of new SQL Server, that I want to create for new web site in Azure. What is problem with this server name?
My configuration:

1. Visual Stufio 2013 Community
2. Azure - free trial

What I'm doing:

1. In VS create new ASP.NET MVC project with Azure
2. Azure settings: new SQL server (TestingAzure73737DB), admin name
   and password.

Result:
Website in Azure created, but with no DB. And I see error in Visual Studio Azure app service activity window: "Servername "TestingAzure73737DB" cannot be empty or null."

Thank you!
Best regards,
Dmitry

Comment: I have tried to create SQL Server in Azure first. Than I have created new Project (ASP.NET MVC) and connect it with Azure. I have selected name of my new Server in dialog box and clicked OK, but than I have recieved new Error: Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App failed. Deployment failed for /subscriptions/582be469-3a0e-4f78-900e-4ffa0b3c62b4/resourceGroups/ResGroup1/deployments/website_deployment
Error in /subscriptions/582be469-3a0e-4f78-900e-4ffa0b3c62b4/resourcegroups/ResGroup1/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/cacv5dsjgu: Server 'cacv5dsjgu' already exists." What?

Answer (score 1):

The server name must be all lowercase!
Furthermore, only letters, numbers and the hyphen are allowed.

Try deleting your azure project and create a new one with the corrected server name.